# How to change the input of a decision operation in the decision center

Tags: ibm-odm

I am using the decision center business console, and it allows me to create new action rules or decision tables.  Also I can add new variables to the variable sets.  But it seems that I **cannot modify the INPUT/OUTPUT** of the decision operation.  I can create a new decision operation, so it seems reasonable that I should be able to add INPUT/OUTPUT variables to it... but I can't figure it out!  Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open rule project map in eclipse and then Add decision operation. Here you find Signature are where you can INPUT/OUTPUT Params.

Comment: thanks!  I found my problem.  It's because my variable names were very long.  If the variable name is more than 50 character (approx) then they will not fit in the "Variables" box.  This results in a horizontal scroll bar and the  ↗ · ↘ are invisible!  IBM sucks at UI.  To make matters worse, if your variable name is more than 60 characters, you cannot even click the  ↗ · ↘ because they are *behind* the variable name!